# java.lang.ClassCastException: subclass cannot be cast to superclass

Tags: java, scala

I changed a class that implements a superclass interface that now looks like:

```
class TimestampConversion(format: String, formatter: SimpleDateFormat) extends ObjectConversion[Any] {
  override def execute(input: String): Timestamp = {
      // hidden implementation details
  }

  override def revert(input: Any): String = {
    // hidden implementation details
  }

  override def fromString(input: String): Timestamp = {
    // hidden implementation details
  }
}

object TimestampConversion {
  def apply(format: String): Try[TimestampConversion] = {
    // hidden implementation details
    new SimpleDateFormat().map(new TimestampConversion(format, _))
  }

}
```

After I changed the code, I started getting cast exceptions when calling this class. This class used to work when it was:

```
class TimestampConversion(format: String, formatter: SimpleDateFormat) extends ObjectConversion[Any] with FormattedConversion[SimpleDateFormat] {

  def this(format: String) = this(format, new SimpleDateFormat(format))

  override def execute(input: String): Timestamp = {
     // hidden implementation details
  }

  override def revert(input: Any): String = {
    // hidden implementation details
  }

  override def fromString(input: String): Timestamp = {
    // hidden implementation details
  }

  override def getFormatterObjects: Array[SimpleDateFormat] = {
    // hidden implementation details
  }
}
```

The hierarchy of subclasses is `TimestampConversion(sub) <-- ObjectConversion <-- NullConversion (super)`

When I try calling the calling my newly modified `TimestampConversion` class, I get this exception

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: 
...TimestampConversion cannot be cast to 
...NullConversion
at...my_parser$$anonfun$7.apply(my_parser.scala:65)
at ...my_parser$$anonfun$7.apply(my_parser.scala:59)
```

where `TimestampConversion` is called here:

```
for ((col, i) <- all_cols) {
   val converter = col.type match {
      // hidden implementation details
      case TimestampType => TimestampConversion("some_format") // line 65 in my_parser
      case unknown => throw new RuntimeException("Met a bad type")
   }
}
```

and it used to be called like this (when it was working):

```
for ((col, i) <- all_cols) {
   val converter = col.type match {
      // hidden implementation details
      case TimestampType => new TimestampConversion("some_format")
      case unknown => throw new RuntimeException("Met a bad type")
   }
}
```

I've implemented the two `@Override` methods from the `NullConversion` interface, and I don't get a warning or anything from my IDE before compiling saying that `TimestampConversion` isn't fully implementing `NullConversion` or something. I merely got rid of the association with `FormattedConversion`. Why am I not able to invoke my class like this? I've also never touched the `ObjectConversion` and `NullConversion` classes.

Here are the superclasses' structures:

```
public abstract class ObjectConversion<T> extends NullConversion<String, T> {

    public ObjectConversion() {
        super(null, null);
    }

    public ObjectConversion(T val, String nullVal) {
        super(val, nullVal);
    }

    @Override
    public T execute(String input) {
        return super.execute(input);
    }

    protected final T fromInput(String input) {
        return fromString(input);
    }

    protected abstract T fromString(String input);

    @Override
    public String revert(T input) {
        return super.revert(input);
    }

    @Override
    protected final String undo(T input) {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

    public T getValueIfStringIsNull() {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

    public String getValueIfObjectIsNull() {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

    public void setValueIfStringIsNull(T valueIfStringIsNull) {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

    public void setValueIfObjectIsNull(String valueIfObjectIsNull) {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

}
```

and this class extends `NullConversion<String, T>`

```
public abstract class NullConversion<I, O> implements Conversion<I, O> {

    private O valueOnNullInput;
    private I valueOnNullOutput;

    public NullConversion() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public NullConversion(O valueOnNullInput, I valueOnNullOutput) {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

    @Override
    public O execute(I input) {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

    protected abstract O fromInput(I input);

    @Override
    public I revert(O input) {
        // hidden implementation details
    }

    protected abstract I undo(O input);

    public O getValueOnNullInput() {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

    public I getValueOnNullOutput() {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

    public void setValueOnNullInput(O valueOnNullInput) {
                // hidden implementation details
    }

    public void setValueOnNullOutput(I valueOnNullOutput) {
                // hidden implementation details
    }
}
```

Also, here's the class that the old code used to extend `FormattedConversion` (though I doubt it makes a difference)

```
public interface FormattedConversion<T> {
   T[] getFormatterObjects();
}
```

Comment: I don't see where in this that the subclass is cast to the superclass? Is the exception caused by external code you run or is it thrown in lines that you have replaced with `//hidden implementation details`?

Comment: Sometimes code can statically typecheck, but classloading problems cause casting exceptions. The same class loaded by different classloaders are not assignable. Following up the previous comment, how are you using the code (which I didn't look at closely)?

Comment: Yeah it's weird because I don't explicitly cast it to ```NullConversion``` anywhere. I put the stack trace + code for how it's being called in the question

Comment: It would be helpful if you could trim out any code that doesn't affect the error and produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), For example you don't call any of the class methods so these could probably be removed without affecting the error.

Comment: I put in the ```TimeConversion``` methods because I thought the problem might lie in the implemented methods. If you're talking about the Object/Null conversion methods that aren't overrides, I can get rid of those